# Back button Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a page where I am making selections using option buttons, Those selections show up as a value. There are options which are selected as default using Javascript as per the code below.

Now on hitting Proceed I go to the next page. Now on the next page I have a back button and when I press the back button, What I want is the selections which I had made on the previous page should remain the same, What is happening on the other hand is, the default selected options are showing up.

I am using this button for the moment:

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" />
```

And this is how I am doing the selection:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h2 class="panel-title" id="selected_part_<%= part.id %>">


      <% @link_text =  "<b>#{part.name}</b> : <span class='selected_part_option'>#{part.options.detect{|o| o.is_default?}.try(:name)}</span>" %>

      <% if part.children.exists? %>
      <% part.children.each do |part_child| %>
      <% if part_child.display_type == "radio" || part_child.display_type == "dropdown" %> 
      <%# @link_text = @link_text + " | <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>" + part_child.options.first.name + "</span>" %>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to raw(@link_text), "#collapse_part_#{part.id}", class: "collapser", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-parent" => "#accordion" %>
    </h2>
  </div>
```

Any idea how do I achieve what I want to?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think either you have to store these values somewhere in the cache (localStorage etc.) and reload them or show pages not as separate ones, but one. If you hide/show virtual pages according to [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) or [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) hash, you will make it appear as navigating through actual html pages and not divs. And you'll need only one load for the initial page.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of Firefox browser is to remember the form's input value. I think in your case, you may use some JavaScript which reset the form automatically, which makes lost the state that the browser remembered.